# python PeFile print bytes of section

Tags: python, parsing, binaryfiles, portable-executable

I am wanting to print the bytes in the range of a particular header. I am using Pefile in python to get the location, and as I understand , it should be trivial to do this, but the address I receive is a virtual address meaning I have the binary loaded in memory.

```
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE("/home/luser/mybinary.exe")

for entry in pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DATA_DIRECTORY:
    print(entry.name + "\n|\n|---- Size : " + str(entry.Size) + "\n|\n|---- VirutalAddress : " + hex(entry.VirtualAddress) +'\n')
```

Section in question:

```
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION
|
|---- Size : 660
|
|---- VirutalAddress : 0x6000
```

I am not certain if it is relevant , but this section is populated in 64 bit binaries for holding exception tables.

if it is relevant here is some test code for this

```
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool myfunction(const std::string& str) {
    if (str == "true")
        return true;

    else if (str == "false")
        return false;

    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Expected true or false");
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    try {
        const bool check = myfunction("not true");
    }

    catch (std::invalid_argument& error) {
        std::cerr << error.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I was trying to extract the table stored in IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION . I might be getting close to a solution , but I welcome better solutions . If it can be solved  by VA rather than raw offsets , then it would be good.